# Command-line host info

Tags: windows, command-line, hosts

What is the equivalent of `host hostname` from [Linux](http://mylinuxbook.com/5-linux-commands-to-fetch-complete-linux-host-information/) in Windows?

For the people pointing me to how to change hostname in Windows, it is not about changing the computer's hostname, what I meant was:

```
$ host google.com
google.com has address 74.125.236.72
google.com has address 74.125.236.78
google.com has address 74.125.236.73
google.com has address 74.125.236.71
google.com has address 74.125.236.65
google.com has address 74.125.236.69
google.com has address 74.125.236.66
google.com has address 74.125.236.64
google.com has address 74.125.236.67
google.com has address 74.125.236.68
google.com has address 74.125.236.70
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4007:801::1004
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

More about this Linux command in [here](http://mylinuxbook.com/5-linux-commands-to-fetch-complete-linux-host-information/).

Comment: If there's a MS-DOS command for it, I'd prefer this way @Steven

Comment: Command-line @Steven

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change hostname in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/334854/change-hostname-in-windows-7)

Comment: ...no? `host www.example.com` does the exact same thing `nslookup` does. It most certainly doesn’t change *your* host name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `nslookup` should provide some of the equivalent information.

```
nslookup www.google.com
Server:  ns.myorganization.lan
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:400b:c01::6a
          204.239.67.98
          204.239.67.102
          204.239.67.106
          204.239.67.108
          204.239.67.109
          204.239.67.113
          204.239.67.117
          204.239.67.121
          204.239.67.123
          204.239.67.79
          204.239.67.83
          204.239.67.87
          204.239.67.91
          204.239.67.93
          204.239.67.94
```

Answer (score 0):

[BIND](https://www.isc.org/bind/) name server is packed with the host and dig utilities and it's available for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/Host.shtml

Host Command for Windows.

It helps when some needs to know the hostname of an IP.